# How to bulk Insert in Elasticsearch ignoring all errors that may occur in the process?

Tags: python, csv, elasticsearch

I'm using `Elasticsearch` version 6.8.

I need to insert ~10000 docs (from csv file) into existing and mapped index.

I'm using `python` (version 3.7) code:

```
    import csv  
    es = Elasticsearch();
    from elasticsearch import helpers
    with open(file_path) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        helpers.bulk(es, reader, index=index_name, doc_type=doc_type)
```

But I'm getting error:

```
raise BulkIndexError("%i document(s) failed to index." % len(errors), errors)
elasticsearch.helpers.errors.BulkIndexError: ('3 document(s) failed to index.'
```

The error occur because some values in the csv file has string value instead of float value.

The bulk stop after 499 documents, and the application crash.

Is there a way to bulk all the documents (~10000) with bulk and if there are errors (due to mapping or wrong values) tell `python` / `elastic` to ignore those documents and continue with the bulk operation ?

Answer (score 5):

You can set the arg `raise_on_error` to `False` since it's `True` by default as suggested in [Python bulk documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.bulk). It should look like this:

```
helpers.bulk(es, reader, index=index_name, doc_type=doc_type, raise_on_error=False)
```

Keep in mind that:

> When errors are being collected original document data is included in the error dictionary which can lead to an extra high memory usage. If you need to process a lot of data and want to ignore/collect errors please consider using the [streaming_bulk()](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.streaming_bulk) helper which will just return the errors and not store them in memory.

You can also take a look at examples 12, 25 and 39 in this [Python ES bulk Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104889/elasticsearch.helpers.bulk)